# Template fields not showing when requesting signature in docusign

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have created a template inside docusign and after added some text fields.
Then created EnvelopeDefinition with that created template's Id.
My question is in recipient side when viewing it, it's not showing added fields, I meant it's not allowing signer to enter data.How to resolve this

I am using c# code.

```
 string templateId = _docusignConfig.ACHDocTemplateId;
            EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition();
            env.TemplateId = templateId;
            
            TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();
            signer1.Email = signerEmail;
            signer1.Name = signerName;
            signer1.RoleName = "signer";
           
            env.TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole> { signer1 };
            env.Status = "sent";

       

 string accountId = _docusignConfig.AccountId;
            string basePath = _docusignConfig.BaseURL;
            var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
            apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
            EnvelopeDefinition envelope = env;
            EnvelopeSummary result = await envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(accountId, envelope);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were using the code from https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-template-remote

You should make sure that when you created your template the RoleName "signer" matches how you defined it. There's a Role in the template in your DocuSign web app, is it called "signer" as well? for the exact same GUID of templateID?

Comment: yes both are same.I need to know if a recipient submit after another recipient can't submit the same template? If can't please tell me how to send same template to different recipients at many times

Comment: @SupunAravinda - are you trying to send several envelopes to unique recipients, or do you want to add several recipients to the same envelope? If you're trying to send several envelopes, you'll want to create a new envelope definition every time to ensure there's no crossover.

Comment: Actually now I'm testing this, I sent same template refernce by several envelops to same recipients.
Let say there is a template called test1, and two recipients called A and B. I have sent that template both A and B programmatically created envelop.I'm doing this using c# code

Comment: and? what is the issue? you see no tags? no signing elements?